# React rendering on load but dont update when the async calls are completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

*I'm having some issues with the components not displaying the info as the async promises are not fulfilled before the render occurs. I am sure this is just something simple, but I don't know what to google atm ;)

I am just using async-await for one api.get through axios, and the promise is fulfilled, just not before rendering of the site. I've also tried useEffect(() => {},[]); but what I aim for is that the site is loaded without any clicking with all the information ready.

I hope this makes sense! Thank you again if you have time to look at it, or leave a comment if there is anything missing.

Thank you!*

### The component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import getServiceDetails from '../../controller/getServiceInfo';

function Customer(props) {
  const [serviceButtons, setServiceButtons] = useState([]);

  // here I get the axios async call \/\/
  const serviceInfo = getServiceDetails();
  // it returns the promise unfullfilled on render.

  if (typeof serviceInfo !== 'undefined' && serviceInfo.length > 0) {
    let buttonArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < serviceInfo.length; i++) {
      buttonArray.push(
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log('test');
          }}
          key={i}
        >
          {serviceInfo[i].name}
        </button>
      );
    }
    setServiceButtons(buttonArray);
  }

  return (
    <div id="customer_card">
      <h2>Customer overview:</h2>
      <p>
        Name: {props.db?.firstname + ' ' + props.db?.lastname} <br />
        Phone: {props.db?.phone} <br />
        Email: {props.db?.email}
      </p>
      <div className="newbookingbuttons">
        <h3>New reservations:</h3>
        {serviceButtons}
      </div>
      <div className="list_of_bookings">
        <h3>Current bookings:</h3>
        <p>
          Here we list all bookings that are current with possible changes
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              // this button does not work... (tried to check if it was different with a click)
              let buttonArray = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < serviceInfo.length; i++) {
                buttonArray.push(
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      console.log('test');
                    }}
                    key={i}
                  >
                    {serviceInfo[i].name}
                  </button>
                );
              }
              setServiceButtons(buttonArray);
            }}
          >
            Manual
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Customer;
```

---

console:

```
Promise {<pending>}Customer.js:29 undefined
Customer.js:30 []
Customer.js:28 Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: Array(1)
Customer.js:29 undefined
```

Comment: React does not know that the async call has completed. React re-renders based on state, props and context changes. try setting up a state to hold the result `const [serviceInfo, setServiceInfo] = useState();` and then using a useEffect to call your async function `useEffect(() => { asyncFunc().then(result => setServiceInfo(result)) }, [setServiceInfo]);`.

Comment: Thank you @JacobSmit worked fine with this improvement. Thank you!!